# Nonlinear regression on tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, non-linear-regression

What activation and cost functions on `tensorflow` could be suitable below for **tf.nn** to **learn** a simple single variate nonlinear relationship `f(x) = x * x` that is a priori unknown?

Certainly, this impractical model is used for the sole purpose of understanding `tf.nn mechanics 101`.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y = some_nonlinear_activation_function_HERE(tf.matmul(x,W) + b) 
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(some_related_cost_function_HERE(y, y_)) 
learning_rate = 0.001
optimize = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
steps = 1000
for i in range(steps):
  sess.run(optimize, 
    feed_dict={x: np.array([[i]])), y_: np.array([[i*i]])})   
print("prediction: %f" % sess.run(y, 
  feed_dict={x: np.array([[1100]])})) 
# expected output near 1210000
```

Answer (score 1):

The COST that is often used is simply the squared difference:

```
def squared_error(y1,y2):
  return tf.square(y1-y2)
```

Plus an L1 or L2 penalty if you feel like it.

However it seems to me that you need a hidden layer in your neural network if you want something remotely interesting. Plus if you squash your output and your target is the squared function you might not be able to do much.
I would do:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1]) 
#Hidden layer with ten neurons
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,10]))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
h1 = some_nonlinear_activation_function(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,1]))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
#I am not squashing the output
y=tf.matmul(h1,W2)+b
cost = tf.reduce_mean(squared_error(y, y_))
```

Also I would not use 0 weights but a more clever initialization scheme like Xavier's or He's which really come down to starting with practically zero weights but not exactly zeros for various reasons.
For activations you might use tanh, sigmoid or ReLU or anything really.

Comment: Thanks. I edit the OP w.r.t `learning from tf.nn`.  IMHO, `tf.square` is too specific. I'm looking for a more generalized nonlinear activation function,  which can also be used for other nonlinear relationship e.g. `f(x) = x ** 3` etc.

Comment: It can be used for any function !

Comment: Supposing your target is `x**3` your trying to match the output of your network to `x**3` so for example you may try to minimize the sum of the squared errors between your output and `x**3` w.r.t your variables !

Comment: For activations you can use sigmoid, tanh or ReLU !

Comment: Or maybe I am misunderstanding your questions but frankly I do not know what you mean. Maybe you want to use a polynom in some_linear_activations to fit a more complicated function ? But then it is not really related to ann.

Comment: Given `f(x) = g(W*x + b)`, where `f` is the target nonlinear function, `g` is the nonlinear transfer function provided by ANN framework e.g. `tf.nn`, apply `tf.nn` to resolve `W, b`. Maybe `sigmoid` alike is the way to go, unfortunately I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: If your assignment forces you to only use one layer I'd say that depends on the data points you have from this unknown f. If you use sigmoid your output will be forced to be between 0 and 1 and tanh between -1 and 1 so it is a very serious constraint for a general regression problem. if you use identity it is linear regression an relu with just one layer like this is just fitting a relu with modified slope and position. But no ANN framework seems to be justified for dealing with this kind of problem that is all I am saying...

Comment: Please tell me if you find a solution to your problem ! Hope I was able to help a bit still !

Comment: Thanks for your followup comment where I'm actually stuck so far. Solving generally nonlinear problems essentially belongs to mathematical or to lesser extent computational domain. Current (multi-layer) ANN seemingly more fits to the sub-problem: classification via optimization.

Comment: I do not completely agree with you as regression with ANN is pretty standard cf YOLO, or time-series predictions or a ton of others. To me using zero hidden layer neural network is not really using ANN as backpropagation is not needed but that is just semantic.